# Package-lock deployment issue for Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I receive a following error despite no package-lock.json, yarn.lock in my dist directory. I use *.tgz files as artifacts of packages in a monorepo. This function was successfully deployed in the past.

> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Build failed: npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @mycompany/common@1.0.0 does not satisfy @mycompany/common@file:./mycompany-common-v1.0.0.tgz\nnpm ERR! \n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-02-22T10_38_22_819Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/nestapi"}

Comment: Did you resolve it? I am having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, out of sudden Node 10 at Firebase Cloud functions is showing such error for any shared lib that is being used by a cloud function inside a NX Workspace (monorepo) :/

Answer (score 2):

The error indicated package.json and package-lock.json are not in sync. Make sure to remove node_modules, execute npm install.

‘npm install’ would install the dependencies, then you'll have a package-json.lock file and CI won't throw any error.

Alternatively, you may also have a look at this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2207).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Comment: After doing bigger cloud functions refactoring I've encountered same deployment issue and deleting `node_modules` with reinstall worked for me. Thanks!